# aspell dictionaries and wordlist

Tags: linux, aspell

I'm a bit confused as to how aspell works with dictionaries:

1. The [online manual](http://aspell.net/man-html/index.html) mentions "word lists" and dictionaries. What's the difference between the two?
2. If during a spell check I press "I" to add the new word, to which dictionary is it added? I checked `~/.aspell.en.pws` but it's not added there.
3. The online help mentions it's possible to dump the "personal" word list: `aspell dump personal`
   But when I do this I get an error message:

   ```
   Unhandled Error: The file /home/pc/.aspell.en_US.per can not be opened for reading.
   Aborted
   ```

And I couldn't find any reference in the online help to this `.per` file. What does it do?.
What's the difference between the "personal" word list and the `~/.aspell.en_US.pws` file?

Comment: I haven't used aspell in ages but I thought this was a good question. It occurred to me that if no one answers, it might be worth asking this question on [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) (be sure to delete this version to avoid cross-posting).  Welcome to the Stack Exchange network!